# Circular dependency on Rails Sidekiq setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, sidekiq, worker

Sidekiq and Redis are both running locally. Sidekiq will process the job if I just use a put statement. If I take Sidekiq out of the equation, the rake task will send a text via the model.

I have more complicated tasks to setup so I want to get Sidekiq going for the app. I'm following this tutorial http://ruthienachmany.github.io/blog/2013/08/10/sidekiq-redis-cron-jobs/.

I keep getting this error when I manually trigger the rake task in the Sidekiq

`2014-11-27T03:55:40.906Z 36691 TID-ouue3wz8o WARN: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Text_Message`

Relevant Gemfile info:

```
 gem 'rails', '4.1.1' 

 gem 'sidekiq', '3.2.5'
```

This is the rake task that calls up the Sidekiq worker (send_scheduled_text.rake):

```
require_relative '../../app/workers/send_text_worker'

namespace :send_scheduled_text do

  task:texts => :environment do

    TextMessage.all.each do |text_message|
      if ((text_message.sentstatus == false) && (Date.today ==  text_message.scheduled_date))
      # Sidekiq code: 
      SendTextWorker.perform_async(text_message.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my send_text_worker.rb

```
class SendTextWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(text_message_id)
    text = Text_Message.find(text_message_id)
    SendText.new(text).send_text_message
  end
end
```

Here is the text_message.rb model that it is calling:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'date'

class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :step, dependent: :destroy

 before_save :grab_phone

  def grab_phone
    self.phone = step.goal.action_plan.client.phone
  end

  def send_text_message(message)

    twilio_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCT_SID"]
    twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]

    phone = step.goal.action_plan.client.phone

    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_sid, twilio_token)

    @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
      :to => phone,
      :body => message)

    self.sentstatus = true
    self.save!
  end  
end
```

Thanks to anyone who sees why I am getting a circular error on Text_Message.

Comment: Looks like `Text_Message` may be a misspelling of `TextMessage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the files for classes are in snake_case, the class name itself should be in CamelCase.

Replace `Text_Message.find(text_message_id)` with `TextMessage.find(text_message_id)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for both of your help. Now I have a new error that I'm trying to figure out:                                                      '2014-11-27T15:58:22.370Z 40881 TID-oxu8xcqgs WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"SendTextWorker", "args"=>[10], "jid"=>"22c1b60328131698d65eb1af", "enqueued_at"=>1417103902.283438, "error_message"=>"uninitialized constant SendTextWorker::SendText", "error_class"=>"NameError", "failed_at"=>1417103902.367975, "retry_count"=>0}''

Comment: Instead of `SendText.new(text).send_text_message` you should be using `TextMessage.new(text).send_text_message` as you don't have a class called `SendText`.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. Last question: '2014-11-27T16:15:28.779Z 42097 TID-oxkvs9kr8 WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"SendTextWorker", "args"=>[10], "jid"=>"87a3640dd4f59ace31165408", "enqueued_at"=>1417104751.387465, "error_message"=>"When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>1417104751.473124, "retry_count"=>3, "retried_at"=>1417104928.778513}'

Comment: It's having issues when initializing the `TextMessage`. `TextMessage.new(text).send_text_message` is not correct as the parameter `text` should be passed somewhere else :)